# FireBug is showing deactivated and I am not able to activate it. I am using FF 56.0.2

Tags: firefox, firebug

I am using latest fireFox version and not able to turn on firebug. It is showing deactivated. can anyone help me how to activate it? As I am not able to search xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug is [no longer available in Firefox](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/10/saying-goodbye-to-firebug/), now replaced by the [Firefox Developer Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools). There's a [guide for migrating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Migrating_from_Firebug).

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing are actually the Firefox DevTools. When opening it the first time, there is a hint explaining the transition a little:

[image: Firebug integration hint]

Note that even the Firebug toolbar button disappears with the release of Firefox 57. The backgrounds are outlined in a [related blog post](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/).

Unfortunately, the DevTools do not provide an XPath search within their Inspector yet. There's an [enhancement request filed for this feature](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=963933), though.

Having said that, you can at least copy the XPath to an element via the context menu:

[image: Copy XPath context menu item]

Furthermore, if you need the XPath for automated testing like Selenium, you can use CSS selectors in most cases instead, which *can* be searched for using the search field.